# Have a <form> Change to Another <form> on Submit, Without Changing Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So basically I have 10 forms, all on separate pages at the moment, when you click next it changes to the next page. I'm trying to have it just set the form to display:none; and bring in the next form, rather than having 10 separate pages. I assume I could do this with jQuery, but I'm not sure how I'd achieve this effect. Any help is appreciated!

Example first page:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
}

a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.jetpack{position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; width:200px; height:445px; z-index:4;animation: bounce 8s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: bounce 8s linear infinite;}
.rocketeer{background:url(../images/rocketeer.png) no-repeat 0 0; position:relative; z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; }
.trail{ background:url(../images/jet-trail.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:80px; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:225px; left:-30px;
animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite; -webkit-animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite;}
.jetenter{animation: enter 3s linear 1; -webkit-animation: enter 3s linear 1;}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }
@keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }

@-webkit-keyframes jettrail { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }
@keyframes jettrail { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }

.jetpack2{position:absolute; top:200px; right:200px; width:200px; height:445px; z-index:4;animation: bounce 8s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: bounce 8s linear infinite;}
.rocketeer2{background:url(../images/rocketeer2.png) no-repeat 0 0; position:relative; z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; }
.trail2{ background:url(../images/jet-trail2.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:80px; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:225px; left:152px;
animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite; -webkit-animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite;}
.jetenter2{animation: enter 3s linear 1; -webkit-animation: enter 3s linear 1;}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }
@keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }

@-webkit-keyframes jettrail2 { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }
@keyframes jettrail2 { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align:center;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #175587;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.note{text-align:center;}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #175587;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="jetpack">
  <div class="rocketeer"></div>
    <div class="trail"></div>
</div>

<div class="jetpack2">
  <div class="rocketeer2"></div>
    <div class="trail2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Integrated Webworks</h3>
    <h4>Website Questionnaire</h4>
    <p>Question 1 of 10</p>
    <h5 class="note">What Are Three Websites That You Like?</h5>
    <p class="note">Please list 3 things you like and 3 things you do not like about each site. They don't necessarily have to be related to your idea.</p>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="First Website" tabindex="1" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Second Website" tabindex="2" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Third Website" tabindex="3" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <a href="2of10.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large"><i class="material-icons right">navigate_next</i>Next</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Example second page:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
}

a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.jetpack{position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; width:200px; height:445px; z-index:4;animation: bounce 8s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: bounce 8s linear infinite;}
.rocketeer{background:url(../images/rocketeer.png) no-repeat 0 0; position:relative; z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; }
.trail{ background:url(../images/jet-trail.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:80px; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:225px; left:-30px;
animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite; -webkit-animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite;}
.jetenter{animation: enter 3s linear 1; -webkit-animation: enter 3s linear 1;}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }
@keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }

@-webkit-keyframes jettrail { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }
@keyframes jettrail { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }

.jetpack2{position:absolute; top:200px; right:200px; width:200px; height:445px; z-index:4;animation: bounce 8s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: bounce 8s linear infinite;}
.rocketeer2{background:url(../images/rocketeer2.png) no-repeat 0 0; position:relative; z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; }
.trail2{ background:url(../images/jet-trail2.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:80px; height:100%; background-size:100% auto; position:absolute; z-index:1; top:225px; left:152px;
animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite; -webkit-animation: jettrail 2s alternate infinite;}
.jetenter2{animation: enter 3s linear 1; -webkit-animation: enter 3s linear 1;}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }
@keyframes bounce { 0%, 20%,40%,60%,80%, 100% { top:200px; } 10% { top:205px; } 30% { top:185px; } 50% { top:205px; } 70% { top:195px; } 90% { top:215px; } }

@-webkit-keyframes jettrail2 { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }
@keyframes jettrail2 { from{opacity:1;} to{opacity:.3;} }

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align:center;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #175587;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.note{text-align:center;}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #175587;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="jetpack">
  <div class="rocketeer"></div>
    <div class="trail"></div>
</div>

<div class="jetpack2">
  <div class="rocketeer2"></div>
    <div class="trail2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Integrated Webworks</h3>
    <h4>Website Questionnaire</h4>
    <p>Question 2 of 10</p>
    <h5 class="note">What Are Three of Your Competitor's Websites?</h5>
    <p class="note">Please list 3 things you like and 3 things you do not like about each site. They don't necessarily have to be related to your idea.</p>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="First Competitor's Website" tabindex="1" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Second Competitor's Website" tabindex="2" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Third Competitor's Website" tabindex="3" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <a href="3of10.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large"><i class="material-icons right">navigate_next</i>Next</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends a lot upon what happens when your submit form at each page. Is the form submitted to a server side script (you don't have action in your form so I couldn't tell)? Or do you wish to keep collecting info in 10 pages and then send the whole package to server side script? Can a user go back and forth between pages? Does a page look different based on my answers on previous page? There is a lot of thinking/planning missing here.

Comment: @Nawed Khan My apologies, I forgot to mention that.
I want the whole 10 pages to be sent as one package.
The user can't go back, the form and button is already planned out.
I forgot to link materialize.css so it doesn't appear, but it's there.

Comment: You could use a tab widget to make each page of the form a different tab. When you're submitting the form, use jQuery to show all the tabs at once, since `display: none;` fields don't get submitted to the server.

Comment: Or you could submit the form using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I'll just write here:

You could simply create one form and "subcategories" those being just div's with specific id's or class.

So something like this

```
<form>
 <div class="formpage">
  <!--Some form inputs or whatever-->
  <!--At the end put some button that call a JavaScript function so that you go to the next page-->
 </div>
 <div class="formpage">
 <!--Same as previously-->
 </div>
 <div class="formpage">
 <!--Let's say this will be the last page so put here the submit button of the form-->
 </div>
</form>
```

Now let's make sure that by default .formpage is hidden so in css:

```
.formpage {
display: block;
}
```

And now some JavaScript.

```
//You can either load this javascript on page load or when some button to start the form is pressed.
//So let's make sure show the first page.
document.getElementsByClassname("formpage")[0].style.display = "block";

//Now a function that will be called when we press the button at the bottom of the form "page" to go to the next one.
function nextFormPage(id) {
 document.getElementsByClassname("formpage")[id-1].style.display = "none";
 document.getElementsByClassname("formpage")[id].style.display = "block";
}
```

Of course you can do it in a better way like give the formpage div some class that has display block or remove a class that has display none or you could go position absolute and do opacity, but I hope I could have given you something to work of.